# ManyToMany doctrine relation with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to make a relationship ManyToMany with two entity:

- User (used with FOSUserBundle)
- Categorie

For the moment, I'm doing this in "MyNamespace/Userbundle/Entity/User.php" :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\MyNamespace\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Categorie", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_has_categories")
 */
private $categories;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

---

And this in "MyNameSpace/WebsiteBundle/Entity/Categorie.php" :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\MyNameSpace\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="categories")
 */
 private $users;

 public function __construct()
 {
   $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
 }
```

---

When I run the doctrine command for create the table with the reationship, everything is OK.

But when I do a `var_dump($this->getUser());` in my default controller (for exemple), I have an infinite loop that crashes my browser.
This effect no longer appears when I delete the relationship in my User entity ...

That would have an idea where this problem may be?

I turn with php 5.4.9 on ubuntu

Thank's :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

> Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump()

Instead of `var_dump`

### **-Updated-**

Why **Debug::dump()** works but  var_dump doesn't:

**Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump()** accept second parameter **maxDepth** with default value = 2 to limit the nested reference to two level. You can pass this value as you like.

Comment: Thank's for you reply, that work's, I have no infinite loop ! But why it works with Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump() and not with the classic var_dump() ?

Comment: var_dump is native php function, and as there is a circular reference created for many-to-many relation, var_dump can't handle, wheres **Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug:dump()** implemented to handle such scenario